# What is the short story about a kid scared of the ocean who turns out to be an alien?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The plot is about this kid with a deep fear of the oceans and the big plot twist of it is that he is really a member of this underwater alien race who crash landed on Earth when he was young. He was implanted with a fear of oceans in order to keep him away from his true nature

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.